# Php url request

Tags: php, request-uri

I downloaded this template off the web, very easy to understand. It is used to detect what device you're using and all. Well, just one issue I am having with it is how the index.php page is setup and it uses REQUEST_URI to figure out what file it needs to pull just one issue when you click it link it moves files so instead of it being on index.php it is now on foobar.php resulting the REQUEST_URI to be useless. I feel like it was attempting to stay on the index.php page when you clicked a link, but it still showed the dir it was suppose to follow. I am unsure but here the two files. Sorry for my poor explanation... Grammar and such was/is never my strong suit.

Oh yeah. I did however took out their detect and replaced it with mobile detect (Which I find much better and updated), but it will still giving me this issue when I was using theirs.

**Config.php**

```
<?php
/*
 * A Design by W3layouts
Author: W3layouts
Author URL: http://w3layouts.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
 *
 */
$current_page_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$part_url = explode("/", $current_page_uri);
$page_name = end($part_url);
echo $current_page_uri;
echo $page_name;
$email_id = "w3layouts@gmail.com";
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php 
/*
 * A Design by W3layouts
Author: W3layouts
Author URL: http://w3layouts.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
 *
 */
 /*
include "app/config.php";
include "app/detect.php";*/
include "app/config.php";
require_once 'app/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

$deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
$scriptVersion = $detect->getScriptVersion();
if ($deviceType == "tablet" || $deviceType == "phone") {
    $browser_t = "smartphone";
}
elseif ($deviceType == "computer") {
    $browser_t = "web";
}

if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='index.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='technology.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/technology.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='blog.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/blog.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='about.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/about.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='contact.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/contact.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='single-page.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/single-page.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='404.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/404.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='contact-post.html') {
    include 'app/contact.php';
    }
else
    {
        include $browser_t.'/404.html';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Detecting browser server-side is a hit-and-miss business. If you are trying to accommodate different screen sizes, make your website layout responsive instead.

Comment: Yeah. Which I usually do but I was gonna try something new, but now I am just trying to understand what they were doing. I assume it something like this... https://translate.google.com/#en/es/hello where hello act like it should be /es?q=hello instead it is /hello

Comment: No; that's URL routing. If you want to do something like that in PHP, using a framework like Symfony, Silex or Laravel would be your best bet. (Obviously there are pure-routing utilities like klein.php but you might as well pick up industry best-practices)

Comment: Okay, thanks for you help. I just found out they did use mod_rewrite, I just had it disabled on my localhost and I missed their htaccess file. This is why I was confused..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to enable mod_rewrite on my server therefore it wasn't working correctly.